# How to download bundles via composer without having an icu version error in Windows environment?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, intl

I found a lot of posts concerning this problem but i think my question is different (my environment especially).

I work with windows seven, Symfony 2.3.6 and wamp 2.2

I would like to download and install FOSUserBundle :

```
php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle
```

I have a (obviously common) error :

```
symfony/icu v1.2.0 requires lib-icu >= 4.4
Installation request for symfony/icu == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony icu[v1.2.0]
```

Obviously I already have the version 1.2 of symfony/icu.

I tried to update it anyway :

```
php composer.phar update symfony/icu
```

but it wanted to install a previous version (1.0.0). why ?

So i kept 1.2.0

I undertood that icu is delivered with PHP intl extension. It is on.

Launcing phpinfo I have this :

```
intl

Internationalization support    enabled
version 1.1.0
ICU version 4.6.1
ICU Data version    4.6

Directive   Local Value Master Value
intl.default_locale fr_utf8 fr_utf8
intl.error_level    2   2
```

So 4.6 is >= 4.4, it should be fine no?

What is wrong ?

How can I solve that ?

Note : 
I did not change the composer.json but the require section to add the bundle I want to add

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*"
```

Note 2 :

Maybe this is related : when I try to download with composer using https I have an exception :

```
You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

The thing is my php_openssl is activated...

so it could be that composer dont see the extensions even though they are activated (neither openssl, neither intl maybe)... I dont know

Comment: could you please add your `composer.json` to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the php.ini used by Apache is not the same as the one use in command line.

To know what php.ini the command line uses, type :

```
php --ini
```

and the php extension have to be set on in the php.ini mentionned. To be sure it is fine, we can type :

```
php -m
```

wampserver does not change this php.ini (normally the php folder one) but Apache one (in the Apache folder).